# Display real time active users to my web site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to display real time active users to my web site I am trying to use analytics API

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#auth

I am able to load real time users but this requires Auth token so I have to login to access the API.

Is there a way to get real time active users to my site without login to analytics account?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics is not an online visitor counter. For that you have [plenty of other solutions](https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?q=online+visitor+counter).

If you really want to access Real-Time data for Analytics, you need to use the API. The API, subsequently, requires OAuth.

The only way to access Analytics data without OAuth is Apps Script. However, it would not solve your issue. First, it does not have access to Real Time API ([article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics)). Secondly, it would be hard to embed it on your website as it does not allow iframing and tends to be very sandboxed.